# Eating disorder recovery

Tags: nutrition

I have an eating disorder. I want to recover right know I am at healthy weight 60 kilograms but eating under 200 calories per day. I want to know how to look like pre eating disorder. How to boost my metabolism without gaining weight. Is my body fat higher than pre ed as I look fatter even when I an at the same weight, or it is my eating disorder?

Comment: This is far too little information to make any worthwhile answer.

Comment: What information do you need to know exactly?

Answer (score 2):

If you have been eating 200kcal a day for any significant amount of time, you should contact a physician on a proper advice on how to start to recover. Not only this is not enough energy to sustain basic body functions like body temperature or heart beat but also such amount of food keeps you deprived from all basic essential fatty and amino acids, vitamins and minerals. Any advice from people that do not know your personal case (and it does not look like a common case) should be ignored.

Your body burns over 1000kcal a day just to maintain its basic functions (and actually for a 60kg person, male or female, no matter how sedentary, that figure will be higher) thus while eating that much, it is physically impossible to store fat. And under that - your body is desperately destroying tissue to try to reduce the energy expenditure. Any weight gain after you increase your calories to a figure close to your maintenance level (and at least 1000kcal) will be due to water retention and stomach content, not body fat.

Answer (score 1):

An eating disorder is going to require professional help, because there are underlying causes that aren't just going to be fixed by nutrition and exercise. You may not even know them yourself. Don't be averse to getting psychological help. When we're ill, we go to the doctor, right? And you don't blame yourself for getting a flu or inflammation. Neither should you think there's anything wrong with trying to fix psychological issues that may be beyond your control. Refraining from letting others help is stubbornness or misplaced pride.

Assuming you are getting help, some points to assist you. First of all, 200 calories a day is quite simply **not enough** and will not be sustainable for any decent amount of time. You are not getting the nutrition your body needs, whether it's macronutrients or micronutrients. If you eat at your TDEE (total daily energy expenditure) you will **not** gain weight over time. Don't worry about it. I'd need body stats beside weight (height, age, sex, activity level) to estimate a TDEE, but it's likely well over 1600 kcal per day. Just eat that every day, and the average weight over a week should hardly budge. You may lose or gain a small amount of weight, in which case the TDEE can undergo minor adjustments (say, 100 kcal more or less) to fine-tune it. Note that I say **average** weight. Daily fluctuations are to be ignored entirely. I'll routinely weigh 2 kg more after a weekend because I tend to eat over maintenance, or be less strict, or eat a lot more carbs, and 2 days later it's all gone because it's water weight. Only a trend line over weeks is any solid indication.

> And how to boost my metabolism without gaining weight.

Strength training is widely considered the best approach. As lean body mass increases your metabolism will slowly too. Weight will only increase in a good way like that. Low body fat and more muscle mass is what many people dream of, and will enhance looks for men and women alike.

> And is my body fat higher than pre ed as I look fatter even when I an at the same weight or it is my eating disorder.

There isn't enough information to go on, such as, did your eating disorder consist of overeating or undereating? If you're at the same weight as you used to be but you believe you look fatter, it is possible body composition changed and lean body mass was lost. But it is also very likely you might have body dysmorphia and pay an inordinate amount of attention to minor changes, or seeing changes where there are none. Increasing caloric intake can quickly lead to some changes since replenishing glycogen and glucose retains more water. Simply ignore this. Things will stabilize where they need to be over time with the right caloric intake and exercise levels.

One thing I can say for sure is that if you continue to eat such low amounts of calories each day, you will encounter health issues. Cultivate a better body image. Eating so little each day must be exhausting; that work can be applied towards something you can take pride in and is actually healthy.

Comment: I weigh 60 kilo grams and my height is 165 cm. I am 16 years old. I believe that I am not burning any calories so that I will gain weight even when eating a low calorie intake

Comment: @user20505 While 60 kg is a normal weight at that height, it is highly unlikely you aren't burning any calories and would gain weight at anything below, say, 1750 kcal per day. If you have reason to believe you are gaining excessive fat for a normal calorie consumption, consult a physician. It could only be explained by a medical condition.